# fetches data from a collection, checks multiple conditions within a single case and continues and display records based on cond in C#

Tags: c#

```
foreach (Ransaktion ransaktion in ransaktionList)
{
    String link = RegistrationStart.Uri(ransaktion.Id);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ransaktion.Id))
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(registrationFilter))
        {
            switch (registrationFilter)
            {
                case Ransaktion.ClientSummaryStatusCategoryFailedServerValidation:
                    if (!ransaktion.IsFailedServerValidation())
                                    continue;
                    if (!ransaktion.IsFailedDuplicatePatientValidation())
                                   continue;
                    if (!ransaktion.IsFaliedPatientAddressValidation())
                                  continue;
                    //link = ServerValidationsMaster.Uri(ransaktion.Id);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

    var SerialNumValDisplayList = new SearchList(); 
            var DuplicateDisplayList = new SearchList();
            var PatAdressDisplayList = new SearchList();
  

     String queueChar = "";
                    if (foundInQueue)
                        queueChar = "+ ";

                    //Providers.Instance.Ransaktion.SaveInPlay(ransaktion);
                    string chevronUri = registrationFilter == Ransaktion.ClientSummaryStatusCategoryInProgress ? null : RegistrationStatusDetail.Uri(ransaktionId);
                    var item = ransaktion.GetRegistrationMenuItemDetail(link, queueChar, chevronUri);
                   
                    SerialNumValDisplayList.Items.Add(item);

                    DuplicateDisplayList.Items.Add(item);
                    PatAdressDisplayList.Items.Add(item)
```

```
 if (subHeaderSerialVal.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            
            block.AppendBoldLine(subHeaderSerialVal);
            Items.Add(block);
            Items.Add(SerialNumValDisplayList);
        }
```

fetches data from a collection, checks multiple conditions within a single case, and continues to check records until conditions are met. Finally, it displays the records based on the conditions. RansaktionList is my collection, where I have all records. inside the switch case,
I wrote 3 if conditions. get records that meet the conditions,
 
     
Records stored in SerialNumValDisplayList, Eg:(SerialNumValDisplayList) This should store the records that meet the IsFailedServerValidation() function,  which checks the users with the status failedserverVal.

*(DuplicateDisplayList  -- This should store the records that meet the IsFailedDuplicatePatientValidation() function,  which checks the users with the status DuplicatePal),                                        *PatAdressDisplayList . As you can see, I used three conditions. after satisfying one condition, going to another condition, and checking. However, I'm not getting proper records for each condition. I want records based on each of the conditions and stored in different 3 variables. Please help me achieve this.

Comment: Your code snippet seems to be incomplete, and the formatting is off. Could you fix that? You can either indent code, or enclose it in three leading and three trailing backticks. And your description of what you are trying to do is not very clear, perhaps you can re-phrase that a bit.

Comment: You may want to reconsider that naming: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ransack :D

Comment: _"I want records based on each of the conditions and stored in different 3 variables."_ - that's not what that code does - _at all_... Can you tell us what those "3 variables" should contain, when done?

Comment: I'd also recommend to avoid double-negatives. Instead of `!IsFailedValidationXYZ` do `IsValidXYZ`

Comment: @Fildor,Records stored in SerialNumValDisplayList, Eg:(SerialNumValDisplayList) This should store the records that meet the IsFailedServerValidation() function,  which checks the users with the status failedserverVal.                                                                                          DuplicateDisplayList : This should store the records that meet the IsFailedDuplicatePatientValidation() function,  which checks the users with the status DuplicatePal),